# Parallel load and LED strip not working with MOSFET circuit

Tags: mosfet, led, circuit-design

I have this circuit below made up, but for some reason the LED strip will not light up unless I disconnect the heater/load. I have no idea why this should be happening as they both work when in parallel.

[image: circuit diagram]

Comment: How many LEDs are connected in series in the LED strip? What colour/nominal voltage? Even 3.7 Volts is below the IRF5305's \$V_{GS(th)}\$ max.

Answer (score 2):

IRF5305 is a MOSFET specified for 10V of gate drive, it's not going to perform well with only 3.3V.  infact 3.3V is right in the middle of the threshold region 2-4V.

replace it with a logic level MOSFET.

Comment: (e.g., the original IRF7416…)

Comment: I think you are right, when the battery is not fully charged the current through MOSFET ends up being way lower than it should be. This makes sends why it works for just the LEDs but not both. I'm going to try out a IRF7416 despite the fact that I will be running it at about 3A continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit already has the LED strip and heater in parallel. When you say "they both work when in parallel" do you mean they work when only one is connected at a time?

Have you measured the amount of current the LED strip and heater use? The heater should be around 2.8A (at 3.7V). Your battery might simply not be able to deliver enough current for both loads simultaneously.